# Plot 2 or more parametric functions MAXIMA

Tags: graphing-functions

In Maple you can plot several questions using the `display()`function
Is it possible to do so in MAXIMA?

for example, draw these two parametric functions in the same gaphic:

```
 wxplot2d([parametric,theta1(t,2,3),theta2(t,4,3),[t,-pi/2.1,pi/2.1]],
        [box,false],[same_xy,true],[color,black],
        [axes,solid],[style, [lines,2]],
        [title, "Hipérbola"],[nticks,1000]);

 wxplot2d([parametric,-theta1(t,2,3),theta2(t,4,3),[t,-pi/2.1,pi/2.1]],
        [box,false],[same_xy,true],[color,black],
        [axes,solid],[style, [lines,2]],
        [title, "Hipérbola"],[nticks,1000]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply multiple functions to the `plot2d` command

```
plot2d([sin(x),cos(x),x^2],[x,0,%pi]);
```

For more complicated plots, load the `draw` package and use the `draw2d` command.

```
load(draw);
draw2d(
    color = red,
    explicit(sin(%pi*x),x,-1,1),
    color = blue,
    implicit(x^2+y^2-1,x,-1,1,y,-1,1),
    color = magenta,
    parametric(cos(t),0.5*sin(t),t,0,2*%pi)
);
```

Finally, press the `F1` key and read the manual.

Comment: But I'm trying to plot parametric functions.

Comment: @AlbertoTorrejonValenzuela In above example of draw2d, the last line shows you how to draw the ellipse as a parametric curve (cos(t),0.5*sin(t)).

Comment: any clue on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008742/change-the-scale-of-the-axes-maxima ?